Run workflow x amount of times
In GitHub Actions we want to run a task x amount of times, where x is an input to the workflow containing the matrix.
So far I've only found the matrix as an option to repeat a workflow. We can create a matrix that runs 2 times like:
rerun-matrix:
    runs-on: ${{inputs.runner-tag}}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        reruns: [1, 2]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/some-action
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.reruns }}

However if we want to repeat something 200 times this will become quite messy. Let's say we have an input, amount-of-runs, how should we have the matrix take the value of amount-of-runs as the amount that it should repeat?
Or is there a different logic that we should use, for example a field we can set to specify the number of runs? We do not need any input for the matrix, we can add everything we need in the with property.

One possible solution could be to:

configure your callee workflow on workflow_dispatch event, and
use GitHub CLI (gh workflow run command) to invoke it multiple times from the caller workflow or the command line as needed.

Here's an example:

callee workflow

name: callee

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  process:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Process
      run: echo "Processing..."


caller workflow

name: caller

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      runs:
        description: 'Runs'
        type: number
        default: 5
        required: false

jobs:
  trigger:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Trigger
      env:
        RUNS: ${{ inputs.runs }}
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        for (( i=0; i<RUNS; i++ )); do
          gh workflow run --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" callee
        done

